# Custom type does not implicitly convert from string for binding

Tags: c#

I created a custom type as follows that is basically a string, but when bound to in WP if gives a conversion exception.

```
public class SelectedProfileName: IConvertible
{
    private string _value;
    public string Value { get { return _value; } set { _value = value; } }

    public SelectedProfileName(string value)
    {
        this._value = value;
    }

    public static implicit operator string(SelectedProfileName d)
    {
        return d.Value;
    }
    public static implicit operator SelectedProfileName(string d)
    {
        return new SelectedProfileName(d);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Value;
    }

    public TypeCode GetTypeCode()
    {
        return Value.GetTypeCode();
    }

    public bool ToBoolean(IFormatProvider provider)
    {
        return ((IConvertible)Value).ToBoolean(provider);
    }

    public char ToChar(IFormatProvider provider)
    {
        return ((IConvertible)Value).ToChar(provider);
    }

    public sbyte ToSByte(IFormatProvider provider)
    {
        return ((IConvertible)Value).ToSByte(provider);
    }

    public byte ToByte(IFormatProvider provider)
    {
        return ((IConvertible)Value).ToByte(provider);
    }

    public short ToInt16(IFormatProvider provider)
    {
        return ((IConvertible)Value).ToInt16(provider);
    }

    public ushort ToUInt16(IFormatProvider provider)
    {
        return ((IConvertible)Value).ToUInt16(provider);
    }

    public int ToInt32(IFormatProvider provider)
    {
        return ((IConvertible)Value).ToInt32(provider);
    }

    public uint ToUInt32(IFormatProvider provider)
    {
        return ((IConvertible)Value).ToUInt32(provider);
    }

    public long ToInt64(IFormatProvider provider)
    {
        return ((IConvertible)Value).ToInt64(provider);
    }

    public ulong ToUInt64(IFormatProvider provider)
    {
        return ((IConvertible)Value).ToUInt64(provider);
    }

    public float ToSingle(IFormatProvider provider)
    {
        return ((IConvertible)Value).ToSingle(provider);
    }

    public double ToDouble(IFormatProvider provider)
    {
        return ((IConvertible)Value).ToDouble(provider);
    }

    public decimal ToDecimal(IFormatProvider provider)
    {
        return ((IConvertible)Value).ToDecimal(provider);
    }

    public DateTime ToDateTime(IFormatProvider provider)
    {
        return ((IConvertible)Value).ToDateTime(provider);
    }

    public string ToString(IFormatProvider provider)
    {
        return Value.ToString(provider);
    }

    public object ToType(Type conversionType, IFormatProvider provider)
    {
        return ((IConvertible)Value).ToType(conversionType, provider);
    }
}
```

The error I get with a textbox that is bound to it is:

> System.ArgumentException: 'Object of type 'System.String' cannot be
>   converted to type 'MyApp.SelectedProfileName'.'

I thought the implicit operator was supposed to make this possible?

Worth noting this is not bound directly, but through a wrapper class that exposes attributes and other options I need for properties in my use case for binding, here is the wrapper and the error is thrown on the value.set accessor

```
public class PropertyValue : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private PropertyInfo propertyInfo;
    private object baseObject;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public PropertyValue(PropertyInfo propertyInfo, object baseObject)
    {
        this.propertyInfo = propertyInfo;
        this.baseObject = baseObject;

        if (baseObject is INotifyPropertyChanged)
        {
            (baseObject as INotifyPropertyChanged).PropertyChanged += (s, e) =>
            {
                if (e.PropertyName == propertyInfo.Name)
                    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(null));
            };
        }
    }

    public string name { get { return propertyInfo.Name; } }

    public string displayName { get { return propertyType.getCustomNameAttribute(); } }

    public Type propertyType { get { return propertyInfo.PropertyType; } }

    public object value
    {
        get { return propertyInfo.GetValue(baseObject, null); }
        set { propertyInfo.SetValue(baseObject, value, null); }
    }

    public bool isSetable { get { return propertyInfo.GetSetMethod() != null; } }
}
```

Comment: What line is the error getting thrown on?

Comment: @Scriven it's actually thrown in a wrapper type that I am using that trys to set the value back to the object using `propertyInfo.SetValue(baseObject, value, null);`, this works for normal strings and such, guess im missing an additional converter somewhere.

Comment: @Scriven the trace end up failing at `at System.RuntimeType.TryChangeType(Object value, Binder binder, CultureInfo culture, Boolean needsSpecialCast)`

Comment: I suspect your class needs to implement `IConvertible`.

Comment: @Amy I thought so too, but same issue when i implement that interface through `Value`, will update code to show what I added.

Comment: @Amy I also added the wrapper class that I am using for completeness

Comment: @Wobbles I think your implementation of `GetTypeCode` may be incorrect?  Can you try it with `return TypeCode.Object` instead?  If that doesn't make a difference, hm, I'm not sure.  Nothing else comes to mind.

Comment: @Amy no change.

Comment: @Wobbles Hm, I dunno then.  Thanks for humoring me :)  I'm keenly interested in what the answer turns out to be.

Comment: @Amy, more digging says that conversions are ignored by reflection (https://stackoverflow.com/a/10693776/3797778) great.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically it looks like converters are not available when setting via reflection, which really sucks for me (ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10693776/3797778).

My instance can be worked around, though not my favorite way to do things, by binding to the objects `.Value` property directly instead of just to the object itself. Requires tweaking some data templates but I think it may work. Also might mean implementing 'INotifyPropertyChanged' to all my types.