# Setting property value via reflection doesn't work while setting it directly works in C#

Tags: c#, exception, reflection, casting, properties

I'm trying to set the value of a property `TargetProp` of type `TargetPropType` of a framework via reflection in C#.
The property seems to be a container for doubles which enrich the double with units.

Doing the following works

```
parentOfProperty.TargetProp = 5.0;
```

While the following fails with a System.ArgumentException "Object of type 'System.Double' cannot be converted to type 'TargetPropType'."

```
PropertyInfo setProperty = parentOfProperty.GetType().GetProperty("TargetProp");
setProperty.SetValue(parentOfProperty, 5.0, null);
```

The following also fails with the same exception

```
setProperty.GetSetMethod()?.Invoke(parentOfProperty, new object[] { 5.0 });
```

What could be different in the first assignment that it works while the reflection assignments fail?

Comment: Please show the declaration of `TargetProp` and provide a [mcve].

Comment: you write "of type TargetPropType" is the implicit cast operator overriden?

Comment: @Sweeper Info about `TargetProp` can be found [here](https://www.sim3d.com/api/2020/html/T_Demo3D_Visuals_ExprDouble.htm). I don't know how to produce a minimal reproducible example if the framework is a paid one which probably only very few people here have access to.

Comment: @MongZhu No nothing changed for `TargetProp`. It is used directly out of the framework.

Comment: There is indeed an implicit conversion operator defined on that. How about passing `new ExprDouble(5.0)` to `SetValue`? (Assuming that is what the implicit conversion does)

Comment: @Sweeper Yes that works, thanks. However, I'm trying to use it in a more generic context. The program reads an input file and a transformation file. The `TargetProp` is given by the transformation file and can be any property in the framework. At runtime the program only knows that some value must be converted to `TargetProp`. That works for primitive types with the SetValue reflection, but fails in this case. Any chance to trigger the implicit conversion or find the matching constructor and use that?

Comment: There is no convenient way to do that. You could keep a `Dictionary<Type, Func<object, object>>` that tells you how to create each type that `TaregtProp` can possibly be of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the property directly to `double` works but using reflection doesn't, because the type of the property has an implicit conversion from `int`, as you [linked](https://www.sim3d.com/api/2020/html/T_Demo3D_Visuals_ExprDouble.htm) in the comments. Reflection doesn't resolve implicit conversion operators.

So you can just call the implicit conversion operator manually, and pass the result to `SetValue`:

```
TargetPropType arg = 5.0;
setProperty.SetValue(parentOfProperty, arg, null);
```

However it seems like you want a more general solution. From the comments:

> The program reads an input file and a transformation file. The `TargetProp` is given by the transformation file and can be any property in the framework. At runtime the program only knows that some value must be converted to `TargetProp`.

I would recommend using a `Dictionary<Type, Func<object, object>>` to record exactly how to create each type of property that you may encounter. Let's call this `conversionsDict`. For example, `conversionsDict` would have an entry where the key is `typeof(TargetPropType)`, and the value is something like:

```
o => {
    TargetPropType result = (double)o; // assuming only doubles can get converted to TargetPropType
    return result;
    // or simply "return new TargetPropType((double)o)" if that's what the implicit conversion does
}
```

You can put all the types that require a conversion in `conversionsDict`, and do:

```
PropertyInfo setProperty = parentOfProperty.GetType().GetProperty(someStringYouGetFromTransformationFile);
Type propertyType = setProperty.PropertyType;
object value = theValueYouWantToSet;
if (conversionsDict.TryGetValue(propertyType, out var converter)) {
    value = converter(value);
}
setProperty.SetValue(parentOfProperty, value, null);
```

Alternatively, you can use reflection to call the implicit conversion operator. The operator compiles to a method in IL called `op_Implicit`, though I'm not sure if this is specified anywhere.

```
// list out the primitive types that needs no conversion
var listOfPrimitives = new List<Type>() { ... };
object value = theValueYouWantToSet;
if (!listOfPrimitives.Contains(propertyType)) {
    var method = propertyType.GetMethod("op_Implicit", new[] { value.GetType() });
    if (method != null) {
        value = method.Invoke(null, new[] { value });
    }
}
setProperty.SetValue(parentOfProperty, value, null);
```

See also [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10689083/5133585) which uses the `TypeDescriptor` API.

Comment: Thank you very much, I've used the alternative method you've provided which works well for my case.